# How can Alexa wait a minute before asking to the user to answer a previous question?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

This is an example of what I want:

- Alexa: "Hey Jhon, can you hold your breath for 1 minute?"
- Jhon: "Yes"
- Alexa: "okay, let's try. 3 - 2 - 1 go"
- (Jhon is holding the breath now)
- [ .. waiting for 1 minute .. ]
- Alexa: "Stop! did you succeed?"
- Jhon: "Yes"

I thought to use SSML with a break of 1 min but I can't because the max is 10seconds.
Of course concatening the breaks can be a solution (because I want to ask another question to the user when the timer is completed and in this way it's all managed in a single intent)

`<break time="10s"/> <break time="10s"/> <break time="10s"/>`

However not the best solution (also for aws lambda prices).

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by keeping silent audio for exactly one minute and then concatenate the string you want to say after a minute. I hope this solves your problem.

Example:

```
<speak><audio src=''/>Your text goes here</speak>
```

Comment: is it the same if I concatenate multiple times the break attribute?
What's the difference?